# Selecting from Different Tables, Sub queries or Joins

Tags: php, mysql, join, subquery

I have two tables; What I need to do is select comments of a given user. I need  cid and heading as results

```
posts
pid | heading | body   | username
1     smth....  smth..   u1
2     smth....  smth..   u2
```

posts

```
cid | body   | username
1     smth..   u1
2     smth..   u2
```

I have tried to use JOINS, mostly INNER . But the answer was wrong. Then I tried with a sub query again answers are wrong, but this time its a different answer than before. Now I'm trying to use INNER JOINS with a sub query together. I don't know if thats possible or not.

Some SQL that I have tried; I won't post all since there are too many things I tried.

```
SELECT `comment_id`, `post`.`post_id`, `friendly_url`, `heading` FROM `post`,`comments` WHERE `post`.`post_id` IN (SELECT `comments`.`post_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `username` = ?)

SELECT `post`.`post_id`, `friendly_url`, `heading` FROM `post`INNER JOIN `comments` ON `post`.`post_id`= `comments`.`post_id` WHERE `post`.`post_id` IN (SELECT `comments`.`post_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `username` = 'chichi')
```

Comment: Do you have any relation b/w the tables?

Comment: not between the tables, but both the tables `username` field is a foreign key on the `users` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your posted query it looks like there is a relation exists b/w the tables

```
`post`.`post_id` = `comments`.`post_id`
```

So you can try using a `INNER JOIN` like

```
SELECT c.`comment_id`, p.`post_id`, c.`friendly_url`, c.`heading` 
FROM `post` p JOIN `comments` c ON p.`post_id` = c.`post_id` 
WHERE `username` = 'u1'
```

Comment: had to add `c.username` part in the where clause, but this works`SELECT c.`comment_id`, p.`post_id`, c.`friendly_url`, c.`heading` 
FROM `post` p JOIN `comments` c ON p.`post_id` = c.`post_id` 
WHERE `username` = c.'u1'`
thanks!! :)